# Rails absolute time from reference + french "ago" string

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to reimport some data that was exported using the "ago" stringification helper, in French.

I have a reference Time/DateTime date at which the import was done, and from there I need to substract this "time ago" difference to find the absolute time.

I need to code the `parse_relative_time` method below

Some sample input/output of what I'm trying to achieve

```
IMPORT_DATE = Time.parse('Sat, 11 Jun 2016 15:15:19 CEST +02:00')
sample_ago_day = 'Il y a 5j' # Note : 'Il y a 5j" = "5d ago"
parse_relative_time(from: IMPORT_DATE, ago: sample_ago_day) 
# => Should output sthing like Sat, 6 Jun 2016 (DateTime object)

sample_ago_month = 'Il y a 1 mois' # Note : 'Il y a 5j" = "1 month ago"
parse_relative_time(from: IMPORT_DATE, ago: sample_ago_month) 
# => 11 May 2016 (it's not big deal if it's 10 or 11 or 12 because of months with odd numbers, just need something approximate)
```

EDIT

Range of values

- "il y a xj" -> x belongs to (1..31)
- "il y a y mois" -> y belongs to (2..10) and "un"
  (for one)

Comment: Can we see the content of `parse_relative_time`?

Comment: Is there any reason that you aren't storing the original `DateTime` value?

Comment: @Wikiti I just don't have it. I don't have control over the initial export format, otherwise I wouldn't go through all this pain :'(

Comment: A simple (and yet complex) approach will be to parse the *ago* value, and convert it to seconds. After that, substract that from `IMPORT_DATE`. So, do you have all the cases that can be used in the `ago` option? Only months and days? Years? Hours? Minutes? Seconds?

Comment: Turns out I only have months and days in my current export for now. So yes, basically a working solution for those two examples (and values ranging from 1-31) would be enough for me to accept an answer. There is just an irregular singular for the month "un mois" -> "2 mois" -> "3mois", etc. No irregular for days.

Comment: Are days irregular too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's divide the problem into 2 sub-tasks:

### Parse the 'ago' string

Since there is no reversible way in ruby to parse an 'ago' string, lets use regular expressions to extract the data as seconds:

```
def parse_ago(value)
  # If the current value matches 'il y a Xj'
  if match = /^il y a (.*?)j$/i.match(value)
    # Convert the matched data to an integer
    value = match[1].to_i

    # Validate the numeric value (between 1 and 31)
    raise 'Invalid days value!' unless (1..31).include? value

    # Convert to seconds with `days` rails helper
    value.days

  # If the current value matches 'il y a X mois'
  elsif match = /^il y a (.*?) mois$/i.match(value)
    # If the matched value is 'un', then use 1. Otherwise, use the matched value
    value = match[1] == 'un' ? 1 : match[1].to_i

    # Validate the numeric value (between 1 and 10)
    raise 'Invalid months value!' unless (1..10).include? value

    # Convert to seconds with `months` rails helper
    value.months

  # Otherwise, something is wrong (or not implemented)
  else
    raise "Invalid 'ago' value!"
  end
end
```

### Substract from current time

This is pretty straightforward; once we have the seconds from the 'ago' string; just call the [`ago`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Duration/ago) method on the seconds extracted from the 'ago' string. An example of usage of this method for Ruby on Rails:

```
5.months.ago # "Tue, 12 Jan 2016 15:21:59 UTC +00:00"
```

The thing is, you are substracting it from `IMPORT_DATE`, and not from current time. For your code, you need to specify the current time to `IMPORT_DATE`:

```
parse_ago('Il y a 5j').ago(IMPORT_DATE)
```

Hope this helps!